# Preventing automatic selection highlighting in nested SwiftUI lists with new NavigationLink API in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16

> This is on Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.2

I'm working on a SwiftUI app with nested lists and navigation. I have written out a basic example demoing the issue. The structure is as follows:

1. The main view has a list of items (type Item).
2. Clicking on an item navigates to a detail view.
3. The detail view has a button that navigates to another list of items (same type Item).
4. When you navigate to this list, one of the items is already highlighted/selected (presumably because it is inheriting the selection from the previous list??)

Code that demo's the issue

```
import SwiftUI


struct Item: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let thing: String
}

struct TopLevel: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            // uncomment one or the other to test
            Programmatic_NavLink() // I need to use this, but it has this weird selection behavior/bug??
            //Old_NavLink() // this does what I want but I need to be able to use value based navigation
        }
    }
}
struct Programmatic_NavLink: View {
    let myItems = [Item(id: 1, thing: "thing 1"), Item(id: 2, thing: "thing 2"), Item(id: 3, thing: "thing 3")]
    var body: some View {
        List(myItems) { item in
            NavigationLink(item.thing, value: item)
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
            Details(style: "programmatic")
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { num in
            Programmatic_NavLink()
        }
    }
}

struct Old_NavLink: View {
    let myItems = [Item(id: 1, thing: "thing 1"), Item(id: 2, thing: "thing 2"), Item(id: 3, thing: "thing 3")]
    var body: some View {
        List(myItems) { item in
            NavigationLink(item.thing) {
                Details(style: "classic")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Details: View {
    let style: String
    var body: some View {
        if style == "programmatic" {
            NavigationLink("Demo", value: 5)
        } else {
            NavigationLink("Demo", destination: Old_NavLink())
        }
    }
}



struct TestNavStack_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopLevel()
    }
}
```

If you use the classic navigation link, it does not behave this way. I want to have the lists be completely independent of each other despite the fact that they may contain one item that is the same as one from a previous list. I have tried adding a $selection input to my list that is explicitly set to nil, but this has the side effect of making the navigation links completely not function. I have also tried passing bindings explicitly set to nil to use as the selection value, but it has the same issue. I would just use the classic navigation link api, but I need to be able to use the value based navigation link for other reasons.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me in SwiftUI not quite clearing out view state better. I would hope that this issue resolves itself as those views containing `List`s get a little more complex to the point that views or view state isn't accidentally recycled under the hood. If it doesn't, drop the Feedback here please!